# Symmetry in the spin orbital coupling Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

The spin orbit coupling and the extra perturbation in the Hamiltonian:

$$H^\prime = a \  L \cdot S + b \ \ p\cdot r $$

a and b are constants.

My plan is to check the continuous symmetry on the Hamiltonian.

For example:

1. Before applying the perturbation,  $L \cdot S$ would commute with the Hamiltonian, and hence the quantity would conserve. But what about the effect after  adding perturbation? The way I plan to check the conserve quantity is  breaking down the $p\cdot r$ part. Now if $ L \cdot S$ commutes with $p \cdot r$, we would say its a operator that makes the hamiltonian unchanged. But is there any faster way to check this without proving implicitly?
2. Do you think it would be wise to check the symmetry by looking all rotational operator first on the perturbation part in the hamiltonian? The conserved quantity I'm talking about are $L_z$, $S_z$,....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first observe that $p⋅r$ is the radial component of the momentum operator. Radial components are invariant with respect to global rotations of space. We also know that the *total* angular momentum is also conserved under global rotations. Since
$$J^2=(L+S)^2=L^2+S^2+2L⋅S$$ 
the operator $L⋅S$ can be written as 
$$L⋅S=(L^2+S^2-J^2)/2$$
that is, $L⋅S$ is, up to resacling with the eigenvalues of $L^2$ and $S^2$, a measurement of total angular momentum $J^2$. Thus, $L⋅S$ commutes with every component $J_x,J_y,J_z$. Since   $J_x,J_y,J_z$ also generate the global rotations, I would conjecture that they commute with $p⋅r$ and check that explicitly. Then, $J_x,J_y,J_z$ commute with $H'$ and generate its symmetry.